Difficulty setting up Oauth, Error (400): invalid_scope
I would like to tune google gemini for a project, and this requires Oauth2.0, to store data. I've been following the documentation.
I have the scopes enabled in the Oauth consent screen, so I really don't know what causes this issue.
The enabled scopes
After I try to log in to set up the credentials I get this error:

Some requested scopes were invalid. {valid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language.tuning%5C%5C%5C], invalid=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language.retriever'\]}

also this one: Error (400): invalid_scope
this is the command I used:
gcloud auth application-default login --client-id-file=client_secret.json --scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language.tuning,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language.retriever'

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Curious. At first blush, it appears (!?) to be a fault with gcloud as your command looks correct and the error for valid appends %5C%5C%5C (backslashes) to the tuning OAuth scope which aren't present in your command. I'm unfamiliar with this service (and these scopes) but, can you try using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language as a more broad scope and see if that avoids the gcloud error? Also ensure you're using the latest Cloud SDK. Is there any reason why your command would be appending backslashes?

Are you using Windows?

I am working on windows yes. I updated my gcloud to the latest version, and tried with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language  but that didn't solve the issue. Also the backslashes are gone for some reason now

"Didn't solve the issue" meaning you received a similar error about generative-language being invalid?

I just tried this using a Linux client and it worked without issue. I suspect (!?) that the issue you're experiencing is due to Windows and the --scopes flag possibly because it contains a comma-delimited list. Perhaps someone on here who's familiar with gcloud on Windows can explain how to do this?

Gemini suggests trying double-quotes (") instead of single (') to wrap the flag value.

Okay I tried it with double-quotes (") and it didn't throw an error on windows thank you for your help

For Windows Command Prompt commands use the double-quote instead of single-quote. Suggestion: Google needs to do more testing on Windows.

First Updated gcloud to latest version.
Second as DazWilkin suggested I replaced the single-quotes (') with double-quotes (") like so:
gcloud auth application-default login --client-id-file=client_secret.json --scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language.retriever,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/generative-language.tuning"


Add the previous version details to your answer as you made two changes: updating and syntax.
